# В базу данных mysql не заносятся символы "|"

Tags: php, utf-8, mysql

Доброго времени суток.
Есть такая ошибка: если в тексте есть символ "`|`" (- это не `l` или `i` это черточка с кнопки слэш), то поле бд после отправки в него текста становится пустым, то есть текст не заносится, хотя до этого на другом локальном хостинге у меня все работало правильно!

Как думете, почему такое может быть? (Кодировка у бд стоит `utf-8 general-ci` и без черточки в тексте все работает прекрасно.)

Comment: очень мало информации, придется напрячь телепатов. Легкий гуглинг показывает, что [некоторые клиенты](http://sourceforge.net/p/squirrel-sql/bugs/909/) неадекватно относятся к пайпу (да, это так этот символ называется).

расскажите, как именно делаете запрос (в php какой то библиотекой) или какой то программой, пробовали ли экранировать, пробовали ли сделать аналогичный запрос с консоли, смотрели ли на ошибки или перед каждой строкой добавили @.

Comment: С консоли не пробовал, делай запрос, скажем, так: 
    
    $add = mysql_query("INSERT INTO stocks (name,image,text,day) VALUES ('$name','$resize','$text','$week')"); 


И, скажем, в $text - значение такое "pfyjcbvsq текст | в бд" тогда запрос проходит, но поле text в таблице остается пустым.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0

Comment: Да, может, и так, что он считает | частью оператора "или" - ||, но там же не пхп, и там он как OR, в общем, капризы программы.

Comment: @dantelol, экранируйте запросы. Подменив $week, я без труда могу убить вашу базу данных.

Там же и проблемы с пайпами должны уйти.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В MySql, если я не ошибаюсь, это системный символ (или как-то так), и его нельзя просто одного использовать - для этих целей есть экранирование. Не могли бы вы пример привести своей работы с этим символом?

Comment: а все просто, как теги форматирования шрифта вроде как |b|текст|/b| - вроде как жирный текст

Answer (score 1):

ТС, ты не думал об, ну я не знаю, ЭкранированиИ, например?
Опасные символы будут уничтожены слешем.
Хотя я не смог воспроизвести этот борбаг у себя на серверах.